# When running a router.post it is trying to get assets in the wrong directory

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

Edit: Not sure if I was clear, it does work on other pages.

My Router.get is looking for assets in the wrong folder and I cannot seem to get it. Set it up to all my other GETs and it is looking for the assets in (/edit/assets) and not just (/assets). Here is my code for my GET for the edit ID:

```
    // SHOW EDIT USER FORM
router.get('/edit/(:id)', function(req, res, next){
    var o_id = new ObjectId(req.params.id)
    db.collection('projects').find({"_id": o_id}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if(err) return console.log(err)

        // if user not found
        if (!result) {
            req.flash('error', 'Project not found with id = ' + req.params.id)
            res.redirect('/projects')
        }
        else { // if user found
          console.log(result);
            // render to views/user/edit.ejs template file
            res.render('edit.ejs', {
                            user: req.user,
                            title: 'Edit User',
                            //data: rows[0],
                            projName: 'test',
                            projStat: 'test',
                            projEngineer: 'test'
                        });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the 404 error I am getting:

```
GET /edit/assets/img/Marshell-University-logo.png 404 5.258 ms - 1719
GET /edit/assets/img/RCBILogo.png 404 5.837 ms - 1719
```

and here is an example of it working:

```
GET /assets/img/Marshell-University-logo.png 304 1.762 ms - -
GET /assets/img/RCBILogo.png 304 2.191 ms - -
```

Comment: Mostly probably you are not giving absolute path for your assets. 

Try using aboslute path for your assets like `/assets/img/log.png` instead of `assets/img/logo.png`. 

Try this.

Comment: Sure enough that was it. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'll put it as answer for future reference.

Comment: added it as an answer for future references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most probably using relative path for your assets instead of absolute path, try using path like `/assets/img/` instead of `assets/img`.